# Need concept clarification for wso2is

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am a 30+ year programmer, but almost all of it was in the semi-conductor world and none of that was with web sites.  I have been given the task of getting wso2is to work with 1 new app and eventually add the already existing apps.  Most of the terminology is foreign to me.  I have read much of the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Introduction),  it is beginning to make sense. I can get it to run and create some of the items needed, user, role, permissions and claims.  But there are some concepts that I don't get from the manual.

Ok I know that what I need to get out of it is simple authorization.
Person->web_app->wso2is->authorization->web_app

We will eventually have several apps that our internal users wish to forgo multiple logins.

So if I have AppA and AppB and I want to use both Apps.  I login to AppA, it sends authorization request to IS and it sends back true/false that all is good for AppA, but now I need to get into AppB from the same browser, new tab.  It is my understanding that wso2is is single sign-on (SSO).  So it looks like I would have to sign also to AppB completely independent to AppA.  Our developers are looking to use curl to communicate with IS. So how does IS tie all this together?

I'm very confused.
I understand users, roles, permissions and claims, at least I think I do.
I've managed to add users with REST and SCIM.  I've had no luck in getting ANY of the samples to work.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is not too late to answer this question. I will try to expalin the steps as simple as possible.

1. Add App A, as service provider in WSO2 IS.
2. Add App B as service provider in WSO2 IS.

Note: Both apps can be ( and should be) fully independent to each other. By that I mean, App A can be java, App B can be a  .net application. They can have different certificates for encryption etc.

3. When you try to log in to App A in new browser session, it will redirect you to WSO2 login page and there you can authenticate yourself with user id and password.

Now when you try to open App B in same browser in new tab, WSO2 will not ask you again for user id and password, rather it will allow you to access App B. All this happens because of SSO.

This is SSO in the simplest way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It is as I understand it to be.